# SSIS C# Script Task: How to match/replace pattern with increment on a large XML file

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching, increment, script-task

There are other similar questions that have been asked and answered, but none of those answers work in what I'm trying to do, or there isn't enough information for me to know how to implement it in my own code. I've been at it for two days and now must ask for help.

I have a script task in an SSIS package where I need to do a match and replace on a large XML file that contains thousands of Record Identifier tags. Each one contains a number. I need those numbers to be consecutive and increment by one. For example, within the xml file, I am able to find tags that appear like this:

```
<ns1:recordIdentifier>1</ns1:recordIdentifier>
<ns1:recordIdentifier>6</ns1:recordIdentifier>
<ns1:recordIdentifier>223</ns1:recordIdentifier>
<ns1:recordIdentifier>4102</ns1:recordIdentifier>
```

I need to find and replace those tags with consecutive increments like so:

```
<ns1:recordIdentifier>1</ns1:recordIdentifier>
<ns1:recordIdentifier>2</ns1:recordIdentifier>
<ns1:recordIdentifier>3</ns1:recordIdentifier>
<ns1:recordIdentifier>4</ns1:recordIdentifier>
```

The code I have so far is causing all the numbers to be "1" with no incrementation.

I've tried dozens of different methods, but nothing has worked yet.

Any ideas as to how I can modify the below code to increment as desired?

```
public void Main()
{            
string varStart = "<ns1:recordIdentifier>";
string varEnd = "</ns1:recordIdentifier>";
int i = 1;
string path = Dts.Variables["User::xmlFilename"].Value.ToString();
string outPath = Dts.Variables["User::xmlOutputFile"].Value.ToString();
string ptrn = @"<ns1:recordIdentifier>\d{1,4}<\/ns1:recordIdentifier>";
string replace = varStart + i + varEnd;

using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
{
 string s = "";
 while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null && i>0)
{
 File.WriteAllText(outPath, Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(path),
 ptrn, replace));
 i++;
}

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right path with the `Replace` method, but will need to use the `MatchEvaluater` parameter when you increment.

```
string inputFile = Dts.Variables["User::xmlFilename"].Value.ToString();
string outPutfile = Dts.Variables["User::xmlOutputFile"].Value.ToString();
string fileText = File.ReadAllText(inputFile);

//get any number between elements
Regex reg = new Regex("<ns1:recordIdentifier>[0-9]</ns1:recordIdentifier>");

string xmlStartTag = "<ns1:recordIdentifier>";
string xmlEndTag = "</ns1:recordIdentifier>";

//assuming this starts at 1
int incrementInt = 1;

fileText = reg.Replace(fileText, tag =>
                   { return xmlStartTag + incrementInt++.ToString() + xmlEndTag; });

File.WriteAllText(outPutfile, fileText);
```

Comment: Thank you userfl89!  You helped me solve my problem. The only thing wrong with it is the pattern match doesn't work.  I have numbers to find & replace from 1 t0 4000 but the one you provided only finds single digits. When I plugged my original pattern of @"<ns1:recordIdentifier>\d{1,4}<\/ns1:recordIdentifier>" back in, everything works beautifully.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  Sorry, what I posted was intended as a generic example, I probably should have been more clear on that.